# How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion?

Tags: jmeter, assertion

How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion ?

How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion ok

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive answer on How to ignore timestamp in Jmeter result assertion if we don't know how does your response look like.

[Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) has several modes:

[image]

- `Substring` - checks whether the response contains the pattern
- `Equals` - checks whether the response is equal to the pattern
- `Matches` - checks whether the response [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) the pattern
- `Contains` - check whether [Matcher.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) function is able to locate something matching the pattern provided in the response

So if you want to exclude the timestamp from the pattern you need to come up with a proper [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp) which will match the data you're looking for and ignore the timestamp.

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't easy to ignore the timestamp in Jmeter. It can be done by taking additional approaches.

[This link](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) provides examples of how to extract regular expression to capture the timestamp from HTTP response.
You should then add **JSR223 PostProcessor** to replace timestamp with a fixed string like this

```
String resp = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
String timestamp = vars.get("actualTimestamp");
resp = resp.replace(timestamp, "fixedTime");
vars.put("modifiedResponse", resp);
```

`actualTimestamp` is the variable storing the actual timestamp from the response.

`actualTimestamp` is the placeholder used to replace the timestamp in the response

`actualTimestamp` storing the new version of the response where the timestamp has been replaced with `fixedTime`.

You can indeed choose different names for these. They aren't predefined.

Later, apply a `Response Assertion` to modifiedResponse hence the response will contain `fixedTime` instead of the actual timestamp (`actualTimestamp`).

Here is a regex to match a timestamp

`(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z)` which captures `2023-07-31T01:02:03Z`